# Is there any built-in AngularJS directive to control the visibility CSS property?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there something like `ng-show` but which controls the element's `visibility` style?

Comment: angular's jqlite includes `.css()` which you could modify the visibility with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered [ngClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)?  You can use it to set the visibility styles and bind it to an expression.

Answer (score 1):

`ngIf` removes the element. There is no other display directive for hide/show elements (except `ngHide` wich is basically the inverse of `ngShow` and `ngSwitch` which is a `ngIf` with statements)